# Restful Service without using Annotations in Spring

Tags: spring

I am trying to invoke the Restful Web services using Spring. I searched a lot and was able to make a restful service using different annotations.

Here is a piece of code : -

```java
@Controller @RequestMapping("/service/")
public class RestService {
   long currentId = 123;

   public RestService() {  
   }

   @ResponseBody    
   @RequestMapping(value="/get/{id}")    
   public Rest getRest(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
      System.out.println("----invoking getRest, Rest id is: " + id);    
      Rest c = new Rest();    
      long idNumber = Long.parseLong(id);    
      c.setId(idNumber);    
      c.setName("John");    
      c.setAge("12.6");    
      return c;    
   }
```

- I had a web.xml + (name)-servlet.xml

Above example has just one method and that method is mapped to a url.

Now what I want is not to use annotations at all in a java class. So, is there a way to make rest services without using annotations? How can I configure all the annotations in an XML file and their (all methods in a java class) corresponding URL's?